# How do you make color-changing text withJS?

Tags: php, text, colors

So, let's say I want to have a piece of text on my website, that changes color every second. I do know how to use JS to change the color of the text, but not how to continue to auto-change it based on certain parameters. For example, cycling through thousands of colors, not just one or two.

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: I am not as familiar with jQuery, so I wanted to use PHP. I thought that it could be done.

Comment: still has to be done with javascript .

Comment: PHP could give you a random color for each page load, but not every second like you hoped.

Comment: jquery is a Javascript library to add more functionality to Javascript. You can always just use plain old Javascript out of the box.

Comment: I just changed the question. Now open the jQuery since PHP won't do the job.

Comment: so you want the text blink with colors ?

Comment: More of fade throughout the colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is a simple way to  blink text with colors

Js :

```
// List of colors
var spectrum = ['#f00', '#f66', '#969', '#00F', '#0FB53F'];
var cycle = spectrum.length-1;
// Cycle speed
var speed = 300;
var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('index').style.color = spectrum[i];
    if (i < cycle) i++;
    else i = 0;
}, speed);
```

HTML

```
<p id="index">Flashing text</p>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/da016aw4/)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. But, is there a way to just have it cycle blue-green and all the shades in between smoothly? Again, thanks.

Comment: Thats what `// Cycle Speed For`

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use html inside PHP:

```
echo "<font color='red'>Hello World</font>";
```

for a loop you can simple create an array with all the html collors:

```
$colors=array();
$colors[1]="red";
$colors[2]="blue";
// soo on....

foreach($colors as $color){
   echo "<font color='$color'>Hello World</font>";
}
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. Please refer back to the question

Comment: i edited my post already to make the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is what you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2k9z61f/)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
var myColours = [...];
var index = 0;
var myElement = /*get your element*/

setInterval(function() {

  /* Set your element.  Are you using Javascript to get your element? */
  myElement.style.color = myColours[index];
  /* Are you using jQuery? */
  myElement.css('color', myColours[index]);

  index++;
  if(index > myColours.length - 1){
    index = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So, if I just want to say, HI. Would it be like this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or vanilla Javascript?  You need to have client-side code running to accomplish this.  PHP is server-side and cannot give you what you need.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var myColours = [...];
var index = 0;
var myElement = p

setInterval(function() {

 
  /* Are you using jQuery? */
  myElement.css('color', myColours[index]);

  index++;
  if(index > myColours.length - 1){
    index = 0;
  }
}
</script>
<p>Hi</p>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2k9z61f/